# Why does the airflow at the leading edge of the wing curve toward the trailing edge of the wing?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Why does the airflow at the leading edge of the wing curve toward the trailing edge of the wing?
Is it because the leading edge of the wing generates high pressure?  High pressure pushes the air from the front edge to the trailing edge?  We all know that air flow cannot change without a pressure difference.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113653/discussion-on-question-by-enbin-why-does-the-air-at-the-leading-edge-of-the-wing).

Comment: The question is unclear and the deleted conversation shows clearly that the OP is confused over the nature of cause and effect. I'd suggest this question be closed.

Comment: @GuyInchbald The air is not moving when the wings begin to move, so the pressure of the air increases.  The air pressure increases, so the air moves.

Comment: See what I mean?

Answer (score 3):

As long as an aircraft and the wind that surrounds it have a relative velocity, you can say that air flows over the wings.

Reason for that is either the engine of the aircraft generating a forward motion and thus creating the relative velocity with respect to the wind, OR

the potential energy of earth pulling the aircraft towards earth and thus speeding it up, again causing relative wind velocity. This is how gliders work.

Comment: When the engine pushes the wing, it also produces high pressure at the leading edge of the wing.

Comment: Okay. So did my answer help you now or what?

Comment: Is there relative wind without high pressure?

Answer (score 1):

A pressure difference is required to maintain fluid flow *only* if there is resistance to the flow.  If the flow is frictionless and there is no compression of the flow, no pressure difference is required.

Imagine that the wing is infinitely thin and perfectly aligned with its direction of motion through the air.  In that case the air will have no effect on the wing and the wing will have no effect on the air.  No pressure differences.

Of course the situation is different if the wing is an actual airfoil shape (rounded in the front, "cupped" slightly downward, and tilted slightly relative to the motion of the wing through the air).  In that case, there *is* a buildup of pressure at the leading edge of the wing, because the air is compressed somewhat at the front of the wing as the wing moves through it.  But the increased air pressure at the front is certainly not the *cause* of the relative motion of the air over the wing.  Instead, *the relative motion is the cause of the pressure difference*.

Comment: The air is not moving when the wings begin to move, so the pressure of the air increases.  The air pressure increases, so the air moves.

Comment: Seems that you think you know everything about this already.  Why ask the question?

Comment: I have ideas, but my ideas may not be correct.  So I asked.

Comment: You are right, your ideas are not correct.  You would make more progress if you put more effort into understanding the answers that have been offered, rather than repeating your own incorrect ideas.